# Gracefully Exiting a While Loop

Tags: search

So, I have this function, which works just fine for me and does what I want it to:

```
(defun mwp-set-grade ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (while 
        (re-search-forward "- Grade :: \\\(.*\\\)")
      (org-set-property "GRADE" (match-string 1))))
)
```

However, at some point it finds the last match, and then throws a message:

```
while: Search failed: "- Grade :: \\(.*\\)"
```

I figure there must be a way to exit gracefully while searching for something in a buffer.  I bet the answer will also help me understand a little more about dealing with errors and failures in elisp, whihc I don't understand well.

Thanks as always...

Comment: `C-h f re-search-forward` -- ask Emacs!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`re-search-forward` has an option for not causing an error:

```
(re-search-forward REGEXP &optional BOUND NOERROR COUNT)
```

You should call `(re-search-forward "..." nil t)` and your while will receive a nil value when no match found.

**Edit:**

As Jordon notes in the comments, there is a more general way of ignoring errors, which is the `ignore-errors` macro:

```
(while (ignore-errors (re-search-forward "...")) body )
```

Comment: Alternatively if the function you were calling doesn't have a NOERROR-like parameter you could use `(while (ignore-errors (do-something)) ... )` to demote the error to a nil value.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. @Jancho would you be willing to incorporate  Jordan's pointer to ignore-errors? thanks so much.